# Trying to access multiple nodes in a for each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

In my XML there is multiple nodes ex. CAT1, CAT2, CAT3,...,CAT(N). and I want to display their values but it's dynamic and based of NUMOFCATS.

some psuedo code for that i want

```
for(i=0;i<NUMOFCATS;i++){
    String string = CAT;
    append the value of i to string; //so if i=0 then string=CAT0
    <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
}
```

so then the results would display the value of

```
CAT0
CAT1
...
CAT(NUMOFCATS)
```

edit: adding some sample XML

```
<root>
    <BIRD>ignore</BIRD>
    <CAT1>fluffy</CAT1>
    <CAT2>snuggles</CAT2>
    <NUMOFPETS>2</NUMOFPETS>
    <DOG1>wolfy</DOG1>
    <DOG2>puppy</DOG2>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/*">
    <fo:table-row height="8pt">
        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-width="1pt"
            border-style="solid">
            <fo:block text-indent="5pt">
                <xsl:if test="substring(local-name(),1,3) = 'CAT'">
                    <fo:inline color="red">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </fo:inline>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-width="1pt"
            border-style="solid">
            <fo:block text-indent="5pt">
                <xsl:if test="substring(local-name(),1,3) = 'DOG'">
                    <fo:inline color="red">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </fo:inline>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Result
a table with

```
fluffy       wolfy
snuggles     puppy
```

and im using XSLT 1.0

Edit: Tried to clarify my question better, sorry I'm usually bad at asking questions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please also show the output you expect (the _actual_ output, given that this sample document is the input). Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example of input and the expected output, and explain the logic behind the transformation. --- Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml

```
<cats>
  <cat0>Hello</cat0>
  <cat1>World</cat1>
  <dog0>Ignore</dog0>
</cats>
```

Xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/cats/*">
      <xsl:if test="substring(local-name(), 1, 3) = 'cat'">
        <xsl:element name="result">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
<result>cat0Hello</result>
<result>cat1World</result>
```

Comment: With a little modification this ended up working perfectly, prob a little slower then i'd like but it gives me what i want. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If speed is crucial then I'd suggest refactoring your XML such that the schema isn't dynamic.